# How do you do a forEach loop on an array containing data retrieved from firebase database JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Here is my database Structure:

[image]

I am attempting to write a firebase function that goes through every barbershop, and retrieves all their Barbers.

In my code below, I have successfully retrieved all the barbershop names, and stored them in an array, which is logged on the console like so:

[image]

However when i attempt to move to the next phase of my function, none of the code in "barberShopArray.forEach((key)" executes, and I don't know why. Even "console.log(key)" doesn't work.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var database = admin.database();

exports.addTimeNod2 = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 24 hours').onRun((context) =>
    {

        var num = 1;
        let barberShopArray = [];
return database.ref('/BarberShops/').once("value").then((snapshot) =>
            {
                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) =>
                    {
                        barberShopArray.push(childSnapshot.key);
                    });
                console.log(barberShopArray);
                return barberShopArray;
            }).then(barberShopArray.forEach((key) =>
                {
                    console.log(key);
                    database.ref('/BarberShops/' + key + '/Barbers/Barber1/').once("value").then((snapshot)=>
                        {
                            if(snapshot.exists())
                            {
                                database.ref('metadata/shop' + num +'/').set(key);
                                num++;
                            }
                            return null;
                        }).catch((error)=>
                            {
                                console.log(error);
                                return error;
                            });
                    return null;
                }));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I did

```
const db = firebase.database().ref();

    db.child("orders")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                const fetchedOrders = [];

                for (let key in snapshot.val()) {
                    fetchedOrders.push({ ...snapshot.val()[key], id: key });
                }
          })
```

For more reference checkout this [link](https://github.com/Nishant-Bhosale/amazon-clone/blob/main/src/containers/OrdersPage/OrdersPage.js) in my repo.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that the line `console.log(barberShopArray)` is working perfectly. After the line `console.log(barberShopArray)` and  before the line `barberShopArray.forEach((key)` you are using a return statement `return barberShopArray`. So the part of the function which is after that return statement is not getting executed. Please remove that return statement to resolve the issue. Also the `then()` method after the `return barberShopArray` statement is not required. So please modify the code as the following and it should work and successfully update the `metadata`.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var database = admin.database();
exports.addTimeNod2 = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 24 hours').onRun((context) => {
   var num = 1;
   let barberShopArray = [];
   return database.ref('/BarberShops/').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
       snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
           barberShopArray.push(childSnapshot.key);
       });
       console.log(barberShopArray);
       barberShopArray.forEach((key) => {
           console.log(key);
           database.ref('/BarberShops/' + key + '/Barbers/Barber1/').once("value").then((snapshot) => {
               if (snapshot.exists()) {
                   database.ref('metadata/shop' + num + '/').set(key);
                   num++;
               }
           }).catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
               return error;
           });
       });
       return null;
   });
});
```

Comment: If i remove that return statement, i get the error message "Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return"

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please try with the code. It should work now.